# puppet resource dependency

Tags: linux, puppet, yaml

When I do puppet apply, I get the error:

```
Warning: Scope(Mod::Cl[title]): Can't load '/tmp/file.yaml' File does not exist!
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value.
```

I specify that loadyaml is a function of stdlib module

However, I want to execute file resource before define resource

Someone can help me ?

```
class mod::princ (

    file { '/tmp/file.yaml':
        ensure  => file,
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0644',
        source  => "puppet:///modules/othermod/file.yaml",
        before => Mod::Cl["title"],
    }->
    Mod::Cl{ "title" :
        tmp_file => "/tmp/file.yaml",
    }

}

define mod::cl (
    String $tmp_file,
){

    $tmp = loadyaml("$tmp_file")

    $tmp[var].each |Integer $i, Hash[String,String] $var|
    {
      $mark=$var['Mark']
    }

}
```

Comment: Reading through https://puppet.com/blog/module-of-week-puppetlabs-stdlib-puppet-labs-standard-library-part-4, it sounds like loadyaml opens a file on the puppet server, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my experience with puppet things like "before"/"require" and sequencing(->) don't work very well together. Try removing the sequencing as probably the file isn't getting created...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even if I delete "before"/"require" and sequencing(->), I get the same error

Comment: Sorry, I should've made myself more clear. You need either before/require OR sequencing. Try keeping before in place and delete the sequence part.

Comment: Unfortunately, i get the same error. Thank you Georgi

Comment: I take my answer back then.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in puppet function call [reference page](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/lang_functions.html), functions are called at compilation time, so it doesn't matter what the ordering is, the function will be called before the module gets executed.